# Sample Code for Remote Process/Application Monitoring

Tags: vb.net, udp, remoting, tcp, snmp

All

I am looking for a bit of inspiration here,  a client has requested me to build a simple remote process monitoring application with capability for smtp notification, when monitored processes go down or come back on-line.  Can anyone point me in the direction of some sample code to get me started.  I have briefly looked at .net remoting as a potential development path, from my understanding of how this works, the remoting architecture would require both a client and remote server component, (though I am not a 100% sure on this one), however if this is the case, then it will not fit the bill, as one of the fundamental requirements is that no additional software can be deployed on the servers which are to be monitored.

Alternatively, if you know of a finished 'lightweight' product out there, which would deliver this sort of functionality then this would probably work as well.

Kind Regards

Paul J.

Comment: One other thing, there is a mixture of OSs involved, AIX, LINUX and Windows, although the primary concern is very much for the windows based applications.

Answer (score 0):

Net-SNMP actually has the ability to monitor processes and send out notifications now.  If you look in the snmpd.conf manual page (http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmpd.conf.html) under "process monitoring" (http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmpd.conf.html#lbAR) and "disman event-mib" support (http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmpd.conf.html#lbAX) to get the two features you need.  Also the notification sending support (http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmpd.conf.html#lbAW).

I don't remember the windows support for it and how well it works though (it looks like you're aiming for windows).